# ExtJS 4: Window maximizing issue when constrained to BorderLayout center region with west region

Tags: extjs

I spent very hard times with this issue. There is two major problem in my sample.

1) Whe I maximized the window, right and bottom edges striped out as westRegion width and south region's height.

2) If I set constrain : true and renderTo :'regCenter' then the window not dockable in left and top area of centerRegion.

Is there a bug in ExtJS or my coding mistakes?

```
 <html>

      <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="lib/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/extjs/ext-all.js"></script>

        <script>

          Ext.onReady(function() {

            Ext.create("Ext.container.Viewport",
              { layout : "border",
                items: [
                  { width : 160, region : "west", split:true,collapsible: true, items: [ ] },
                  { height : 60, region : "north", items: [ ] },
                  { id : "regCenter", region : "center" }
                ]
              }
            );

            Ext.create("Ext.window.Window",
              { maximizable : true, width : 350, height : 440,
                constrainHeader : true, constrainTo : "regCenter",
                dockedItems : [
                  { xtype : "toolbar", dock : "bottom",
                    items : [ { text : "etc" } ]
                  }
                ],
                items : [ ]
              }
            ).show();

          });

        </script>

      </head>

      <body></body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating the window after center region renders works, fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/131

Comment: If the window is `constrain`ed, logic requires, that the constraining component must be rendered before the window is rendered